# How can I use RLIKE MySQL function inside of SQL Server 2005?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to run a RLIKE query on a database mmoved from MySQL to SQL Server 2005 however having problems replicating the "RLIKE" functionality that MySQL provides.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know of to do that is to add user defined CLR functions.

To begin with, here's an MSDN Magazine article, "[Regular Expressions Make Pattern Matching And Data Extraction Easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)"

The code for that article, which I've been using for a couple of years now, is [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/Regex2007_02.exe).

Comment: I was hoping there was a nicer way of doing this but I guess this is the only way, cheers!